# Ajax and Rails 4 - How to render the same json when hitting refresh the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to be able to reload the same ajax partial when hitting the button refresh or command + r? When I refresh the page it reloads the `show.html.erb` but not the ajax partial in the div.

Same issue if I hit the button back or go forward.

Any solutions?

```
<div class="bg-grey">
    <% if @user.student? %>
        <%= render 'profiles/student' %>
     <% end %>

     <% if @user.company? %>
         <%= render 'profiles/company' %>
     <% end %>

  </div>
```

So basically if the student is logged in there would be a partial called _student.html.erb rendered with a div#dashboard. Each ajax called would be reloaded within the div#dashboard

Here is the sidebar:

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
          <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
             <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                 <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <%= link_to "W.", root_path %>
                  </li>


                  <li>
                    <%= link_to profile_path(current_user), remote: true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-tachometer'></i> <span>Dashboard</span> <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>"}  do %>
                <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                <% end %>
            </li>
            <li>
               <%= link_to lectures_path, remote: true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-book'></i> Courses <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>"} do %>
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i></i> <span>Courses</span>
                <% end %>
            </li>
             <li>
                <%= link_to projects_path, remote: true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-sticky-note'></i> <span>Projects</span> <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>"} do %>
                <i class="fa fa-sticky-note"></i> <span>Projects</span>
                <% end %>
            </li>
            <li>
                <%= link_to edit_user_registration_path, remote: true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-cog'></i> <span>Settings</span> <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>"} do %>
                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span>Settings</span>
                <% end %>
            </li>


            <li>
                <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>
                 <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <span>Sign Out</span>
                 <% end %>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    </div>
```

Comment: How is the ajax partial being called in the first place?

Comment: @trh just edited the question

Comment: Do you have javascript that's automatically making ajax calls when you visit the page?

Comment: I do not have this, what do you mean? @trh

Comment: You said you have a sidebar with ajax partial.  Something has to trigger those to be populated.  What is it?

Comment: edited with some text and the code @thr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92328/discussion-between-trh-and-adriennhm).